# add custom value for "type" column in laravel default notification table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I am using laravel's default notification system. The type column of the table gets populated by full class path like "App\Notifications\Upvoted" . I am only filling the data column by myself like this:

```
public function toDatabase($notifiable)
 {
     return [
         "post" => $this->post,
         "user" => Auth::user()
     ];
 }
```

How can I add custom value for "type" column too.

As I am new to Laravel your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do this because the `type` Field is following morph rules in the Laravel framework.

If you need to save extra data in Notification Table you can pass in an array and then add as a JSON field in `data` field.

For instance you return:

```
public function toArray($notifiable)
{
    return [
        'post_id' => $this->post_id,
        'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
    ];
}
```

And the result in notifacation data field will be:

```
{ "post_id": "2", "user_id": "1" }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the value of `type` for broadcast and database channels.

For Database channel you must add the method `databaseType` to your notification. See:
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/10.x/src/Illuminate/Notifications/Channels/DatabaseChannel.php#L35

For Broadcast channel you must add the method `broadcastType` to your notification. See:
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/10.x/src/Illuminate/Notifications/Events/BroadcastNotificationCreated.php#L108